# Full wave rectifier with inductor filter

Tags: filter, inductor, bridge-rectifier

The capacitor-only bridge rectifier can't remove the ripple under heavy load and for a linear lab power supply I need to have an output without any ripple under load. after [simulating](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+32.755850052045055+53+5+50%0Av+96+352+96+64+0+1+50+24+0+0+0.159154943092%0Aw+96+64+240+64+0%0Aw+240+64+240+128+0%0Ad+240+128+304+192+2+1N5711%0Ad+240+256+304+192+2+1N5711%0Ad+176+192+240+128+2+1N5711%0Ad+176+192+240+256+2+1N5711%0Aw+240+256+240+352+0%0Aw+240+352+96+352+0%0Aw+176+192+176+288+0%0Aw+304+192+352+192+0%0Aw+176+288+352+288+0%0Ac+352+192+352+288+0+0.0022+9.646637884894336%0Al+352+192+416+192+0+0.1+1.0345115327021326%0Ac+416+192+416+288+0+0.0022+9.438106567198595%0Aw+464+192+416+192+0%0Aw+464+288+416+288+0%0Aw+416+288+352+288+0%0Ar+352+144+416+144+0+0.000001%0Aw+496+192+464+192+0%0Aw+464+288+560+288+0%0Ap+464+192+464+288+1+0%0A370+496+192+560+192+1+0%0Ar+560+192+560+288+0+9%0Ao+0+64+0+4099+40+6.4+0+2+0+3%0Ao+23+64+0+4099+20+1.6+1+2+23+3%0A) the bridge rectifier circuit under 1A load I ended up with this;

Ripple without an inductor:
[image]

Ripple with an inductor:
[image]

*The transformer is 24/1A and diodes are schottky.*

Considering it's going to pass trough a linear regulator which will reduce the ripple to some degree and with such low power transformer, do I really need to reduce the ripple to almost nothing by adding an inductor? or is it better to have the inductor there regardless of the transformer power?

Comment: An output without ripple is naive.

Comment: @Andyaka What do you mean by naive?

Comment: Be realistic is what I’m advising.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't have the knowledge and experience that you have, when pointing at something please explain plainly. In a "realistic" situation what should I expect? "naive" in what context?

Comment: 24 V into 1 Ω will be 24 A. Why would you use a linear regulator for this? If you are using a regulator why would you use a choke / inductor?

Comment: A 1 ohm load with circa 24 volts is 24 amps or about 500 watts. It seems that you need to be much clearer as to your requirements too.

Comment: @Transistor The PSU have the current limit feature that will not let the load pull more than 1A. that's what I'm asking, do I need the inductor or the regulator will remove the ripple?

Comment: For a linear regulator Vin must be >= Vout + min headroom at Imax. Output ripple is >= input ripple - dB attenuation spec of regulator. I say <= as you can't (usually) get better than spec and Murphy will 'help you' get less than spec. So IF the regulator rejection is adequate fpr your need with a cap filter then you can use one. If not you need to improve the filter. || Note: Add some small input resistance to "spread" cap charging peak - or use an L in filter.

Comment: If the psu is 1A limited at 24V then with 1 Ohm you will get about 1 Volt in the load. (V = IR = 1 x 1 = 1. Yes? || You need to tell us what you are REALLY doing as that indicates "summat agalae".

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I just made the load bigger to test the ripple. all I'm trying to do is to have an output without ripple at 1A. So basically using an inductor is not going to do any harm and it's better to have one in circuit, yet I don't need one because of the current limit feature. correct?

Comment: A lab PSU has several tricks, Tektronix, HP, ...others. It can have pre-regulators and  low pass filters, the ouptut tipple can be low as 30 microvolts. Look here for a DIY: https://www.circuitsonline.net/forum/view/110029

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Thanks but the link you provided is in Dutch...

Comment: A LDO is going to remove that ripple by 40-80dB depending on the exact one. You also could chain 2 in series... I doubt your 120hz noise here is going to do much with appropriate regulation down stream.

Comment: @ElectronSurf By using a 1 Ohm load on a 24V , 1A limited psu you drive it deep deep deep into current limiting and the results are very likely not representative of any normal use. Better is 25+ Ohms so it is ALMOST in limiting but wholly NOT in limiting.

Comment: The inductor and the current limit are essentially not related. A post rectification filter of AC gives ripple. How you deal with it relates to when the supply is NOT in limiting.

Comment: Google translate is your friend. You have also the same project (author: blackdog) commented in eevblog : https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/very-low-noise-preregulator-for-benchtop-power-supply/  Many usefull info even if it dutch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand right, Your question whether you should require little to no ripple in the output voltage from your power supply.

Well, all power supplies in the world have some ripple and typically circuits that eventually are the power consumers will tolerate some ripple. In general you would not want your power supply to provide lesser ripple then what your consumer desires because that would add drastically to the cost and complexity of your power supply. As an example you have used 2.2mF capacitor and 100mH inductors. A 2.2mF capacitor of 50V or above would be a gigantic one. A 200mH 2Ampere inductor wouldn't be a small component either.

In your specific case the answer depends on the type of linear regulator you are planning to use. Lets say you want to use a 5V regulator like a 7805 then having fair ripple like around 8 to 10V could easily be tolerated. Typically linear regulators have internal or external feedback loops to compensate for output voltage changes against a reference but you wouldn't have to worry about that considering that the ripple frequency is going to be around 100Hz(the rectifier doubles the frequency as the waveform is just one sided). The max allowed ripple will depend on the final regulated voltage that you desire. So your linear regulator's datasheet will dictate what is the minimum input voltage it can have and still provide a stable constant output.

Now all being said, in short, if you are eventually going yo use a low voltage linear regulator, it seems you dont need such large inductor or capacitors.

If you have further interest in low ripple power converters and that without using very large components, you should study high frequency/switch mode converters. Typically switched converters would feature an IC/microcontroller that would switch a device(mosfet) using a high frequency PWM to achieve target output voltage and that too without a very large size of components.

FYI thats how phone chargers that used to be really bulky suddenly got so compact around 2 decades ago because all of them now use SMPS.

Best of luck learning.